# Php How to get full text from stdClass Object

Tags: php, stdclass

I'm using:

```
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
```

to get emails and when I print out with print_r I'm getting:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [subject] => FW: CRAFT FAIR
        [from] => Bob Smith
```

the problem is the [from] is actually:

```
        [from] => Bob Smith <bsmith@gmail.com>
```

how do I get the second part to show up?

Comment: Wrap it in a `<pre>` tag or `echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($overview, true));`

Comment: Hello check if this will bring light in your journey -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/3435293/5452965. I think `[from] => Bob Smith <bsmith@gmail.com>` is not actually this but you want it to be :)

Comment: I tried echo '<pre>' ; print_r($overview); echo '</pre>'; but that didn't work.  htmlspecialchars gave the full version

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language, please do not use the [tag:p] tag.